# Curl request limit to 100 results

Tags: php, curl, limit

I'm trying to request a list of user in OneLogin in Php.

Here is my script :

```
<?php    
$url = "https://app.onelogin.com/api/v2/users.xml";
$headers = array('Content-type: application/xml');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'MY_API_KEY');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);



$http_result = curl_exec($ch);
$error       = curl_error($ch);
$http_code   = curl_getinfo($ch ,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo $http_result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

My problem is that it is returning only 100 result when it should return more than 4000 results.
Is there something I'm missing? I'm looking for LIMIT, or pagination in [OneLogin API Doc](https://onelogin.zendesk.com/forums/123045-API)

When I query directly in Terminal with command :

```
 curl -u API_KEY:passw https://app.onelogin.com/api/v2/users.xml > curl.xml
```

it happens the same thing.

I don't understand what should happen

Comment: Likely the OneLogin API has a limit of 100 results returned in queries of this nature. Check the API docs.

Comment: I didn't find such a thing in the docs! A link would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't have one - I was just making the suggestion. It's common for APIs to limit remote request responses to a certain number of records. YouTube, for example, limits to 50 (I think) videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the OneLogin API. The [docs](https://developers.onelogin.com/docs/get-all-users) state "the call will return a list of up to 100 users".